# Creating X Number of Nameless Objects

Tags: c++, object

In a lot online judge problems, the format for the input is as follows: first line is the number of test cases. Let's say X. Then X lines after that are the conditions for each test case.

In the example below, there are two test cases. Each test case specify the upper and lower bound for which primes should be shown in the output.

```
Input:
2
1 10
3 5

Output:
2
3
5
7

3
5
```

Now for my question. Right now, my program can handle one test case like so:

```
int main()
{
    TestCase t;
    t.setRange();

    t.compute();
    t.print();
}
```

How can I create X amount of TestCases without naming them all 't'? 
X is specified at rumtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a `std::vector<TestCase> allofem;` and `allofem.push_back(TestCase())` `X` times; remember to `#include <vector>` of course. Then you can loop on `allofem` and compute and then print on each item.

Comment: To make use of each test case, do I do this? for(int i=0; i<numTestCase; i++) { allofem[i].setRange(); }

Comment: If .setRange is what you want to call on each test case instance, yep, this is workable (not the typical style of loops in C++'s standard library, but it will work fine, so if this is what youre comfortable with, go for it!).

Comment: I suppose the typical style would be to use an iterator. I'll do that. Thanks

Comment: @medikgt yep: typical style is `for(std::vector<TestCase>::iterator i = allofem.begin(); i != allofem.end(); ++i) i->setRange();` and the like, exactly. But using an int index also works!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfTestCases; ++i) {  
    TestCase t;
    t.setRange();

    t.compute();
    t.print(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you have two options to create objects: stack or heap.

To create it on the stack you'd run a for loop and declare a variable normally like `TestCase t`.

The other way is to create it on the heap. This dynamically creates x number of TestCase objects.

```
TestCase ** tests = new (* TestCase)[x];
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  tests[i] = new TestCase();
} // for i
```

Comment: You should be using a `std::vector`.